# Graph Like model in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, graph, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I been trying to create a model for an authorization service in Dynamo DB. The service has multiple entities like Applications, Roles, Functional Abilities (FA) and secured entitites (SE). This is a representation of the relationships it may have

```
      APP1
    /       \
 Role1      Role 2
  /        /      \
 FA1       FA2    FA1 
  |         |       |
 SE1       SE2     SE1
```

As you can see the FA1 is the same for Role1 and Role2 and I'm having a hard time finding a model that can handle access patterns like:

***Give me all the Roles, FAs, and SEs for a given application***

***Update the SE1 and reflect that change in all the FAs that are related to it***

I have been reviewing some articles like:

https://www.vishnudevarakonda.com/software/2023/08/15/Modeling-Graph-Database-on-Dynamodb.html

https://medium.com/developing-koan/modeling-graph-relationships-in-dynamodb-c06141612a70

and I think that maybe a graph design could fulfill my requirements as there are several shared nodes. But I wanted to ask you guys if you have any suggestions or articles that I could review in order to accomplish this.

I have started by creating a model where the partition keys are nodes and sort keys serve like edges. It works if I want to know the direct relationships but I'm having trouble getting all the descendants of a node.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PIyy.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is DynamoDb a requirement? Dynamo is not meant for handling relationships. I think a simple relational database might do the trick.

Comment: Hello, yeah that is a requirement from the client architecture